# Problem extracting the correct value from specific element

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import login as login
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
x = x.strftime("%b %d")

driver = browser = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://connect.garmin.com/modern/activities")

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element("name", "username").send_keys(login.username)

driver.find_element("name", "password").send_keys(login.password)
driver.find_element("name", "password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element("name", "search").send_keys("Reading")
driver.find_element("name", "search").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "unit")
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[2]/span[1]")
print(element.text)
```

So this is my code. I am trying to get a value from "unit", or the XPATH at the bottom. Problem is, in the HTML it says that the value is "Aug 25" but when I print it in my IDE it says Sep 10. Since I am using this to check if I am extracting the correct data points I need this to work, but unsure where it goes wrong.

[image: Image of website and HTML]

There is also no other element on the page with "Sep 10" as the value in the HTML.

```
Array(6) [ span.unit, span.unit, span.unit, span.unit, span.unit, span.unit
 ]
​
0: <span class="unit">
​​
accessKey: ""
​​
accessKeyLabel: ""
​​
assignedSlot: null
​​
attributes: NamedNodeMap [ class="unit" ]
​​
baseURI: "https://connect.garmin.com/modern/activities?search=Reading"
​​
childElementCount: 0
​​
childNodes: NodeList [ #text
 ]
​​
children: HTMLCollection { length: 0 }
​​
classList: DOMTokenList [ "unit" ]
​​
className: "unit"
​​
clientHeight: 22
​​
clientLeft: 0
​​
clientTop: 0
​​
clientWidth: 70
​​
contentEditable: "inherit"
​​
dataset: DOMStringMap(0)
​​
dir: ""
​​
draggable: false
​​
enterKeyHint: ""
​​
firstChild: #text "Aug 25"
​​
firstElementChild: null
​​
hidden: false
​​
id: ""
​​
innerHTML: "Aug 25"
​​
innerText: "Aug 25"
​​
inputMode: ""
​​
isConnected: true
​​
isContentEditable: false
​​
lang: ""
​​
lastChild: #text "Aug 25"
​​
lastElementChild: null
​​
localName: "span"
​​
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
​​
nextElementSibling: <span class="label">​​
nextSibling: #text "\n        "
​​
nodeName: "SPAN"
​​
nodeType: 1
​​
nodeValue: null
​​
nonce: ""
​​
offsetHeight: 22
​​
offsetLeft: 50
​​
offsetParent: <li class="list-item animated row-fluid">
​​
offsetTop: 3
​​
offsetWidth: 70
​​
onabort: null
​​
onanimationcancel: null
​​
onanimationend: null
​​
onanimationiteration: null
​​
onanimationstart: null
​​
onauxclick: null
​​
onbeforeinput: null
​​
onblur: null
​​
oncanplay: null
​​
oncanplaythrough: null
​​
onchange: null
​​
onclick: null
​​
onclose: null
​​
oncontextmenu: null
​​
oncopy: null
​​
oncuechange: null
​​
oncut: null
​​
ondblclick: null
​​
ondrag: null
​​
ondragend: null
​​
ondragenter: null
​​
ondragexit: null
​​
ondragleave: null
​​
ondragover: null
​​
ondragstart: null
​​
ondrop: null
​​
ondurationchange: null
​​
onemptied: null
​​
onended: null
​​
onerror: null
​​
onfocus: null
​​
onformdata: null
​​
onfullscreenchange: null
​​
onfullscreenerror: null
​​
ongotpointercapture: null
​​
oninput: null
​​
oninvalid: null
​​
onkeydown: null
​​
onkeypress: null
​​
onkeyup: null
​​
onload: null
​​
onloadeddata: null
​​
onloadedmetadata: null
​​
onloadend: null
​​
onloadstart: null
​​
onlostpointercapture: null
​​
onmousedown: null
​​
onmouseenter: null
​​
onmouseleave: null
​​
onmousemove: null
​​
onmouseout: null
​​
onmouseover: null
​​
onmouseup: null
​​
onmozfullscreenchange: null
​​
onmozfullscreenerror: null
​​
onpaste: null
​​
onpause: null
​​
onplay: null
​​
onplaying: null
​​
onpointercancel: null
​​
onpointerdown: null
​​
onpointerenter: null
​​
onpointerleave: null
​​
onpointermove: null
​​
onpointerout: null
​​
onpointerover: null
​​
onpointerup: null
​​
onprogress: null
​​
onratechange: null
​​
onreset: null
​​
onresize: null
​​
onscroll: null
​​
onsecuritypolicyviolation: null
​​
onseeked: null
​​
onseeking: null
​​
onselect: null
​​
onselectionchange: null
​​
onselectstart: null
​​
onslotchange: null
​​
onstalled: null
​​
onsubmit: null
​​
onsuspend: null
​​
ontimeupdate: null
​​
ontoggle: null
​​
ontransitioncancel: null
​​
ontransitionend: null
​​
ontransitionrun: null
​​
ontransitionstart: null
​​
onvolumechange: null
​​
onwaiting: null
​​
onwebkitanimationend: null
​​
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
​​
onwebkitanimationstart: null
​​
onwebkittransitionend: null
​​
onwheel: null
​​
outerHTML: "<span class=\"unit\">Aug 25</span>"
​​
outerText: "Aug 25"
​​
ownerDocument: HTMLDocument https://connect.garmin.com/modern/activities?search=Reading
​​
parentElement: <div class="pull-left activity-date date-col">​​
parentNode: <div class="pull-left activity-date date-col">​​
part: DOMTokenList []
​​
prefix: null
​​
previousElementSibling: null
​​
previousSibling: #text "\n        "
​​
scrollHeight: 22
​​
scrollLeft: 0
​​
scrollLeftMax: 0
​​
scrollTop: 0
​​
scrollTopMax: 0
​​
scrollWidth: 70
​​
shadowRoot: null
​​
slot: ""
​​
spellcheck: false
​​
style: CSS2Properties(0)
​​
tabIndex: -1
​​
tagName: "SPAN"
​​
textContent: "Aug 25"
​​
title: ""
​​
<prototype>: HTMLSpanElementPrototype { … }
​
1: <span class="unit" title="0.00 km">​
2: <span class="unit" title="34:22">​
3: <span class="unit" title="--">​
4: <span class="unit" title="97 bpm">​
5: <span class="unit" title="120">
​
length: 6
```

Comment: Try running that page with JS disabled: you will likely find the default value 'Sep 10' in page source. If you want your script to succeed in getting that data, you should use explicit Waits: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ Also, that xpath is really, really fragile: try using a more robust locator.

Comment: Page can't be run with JS disabled. How would explicit waits help? Sure, but that isn't really the problem at the moment. I have been trying to fix this for quite some time and it has been a hard task. Just added another implicit wait in-between, but same result, "Sep 10".

Comment: `implicitly_wait()` does not actually wait when called, it is setting the timeout and is once per driver instance. If used, it should be set at the start of your script and then it doesn't need to be set again. Having said that, the creator of WebDriver has said not to use it. You should instead use `WebDriverWait` when a wait is needed. This isn't relevant to the problem, just an observation.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as text in your question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Once on the page, open the dev console and type `$$("span.unit")`. How many elements are returned?

Comment: What is printed if you uncomment the first `element` line and comment out the second?

Comment: Same thing, also Sep 10. There are 6 elements, the others are the integers from the screenshot. The only one with a date is the first one, Aug 25, the one that returns Sep 10. I have had issues with WebDriverWait, and when using "By.XPATH, "*****") it says it's too many arguments, some kind of syntax error.

Can you specify what HTML is relevant?

Comment: Testing account if you want to try it out yourself. https://connect.garmin.com/modern/activities Username: aigtglxpzepqjiitjc@nthrl.com Password: Easypass1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hard wait, in case you are missing something.
Visit [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep) page to get more idea.

Use the following code to target the element.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='pull-left activity-date date-col']/span[1])[1]")
print(element.text)
```

Also, please share the HTML Source to frame the problem better.